# Python 2.7 MRO behaves strangely

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

so I've been doing a bit of research into the wonderful world of Python 2.7 Multiple inheritance and MROs and I've been trying out different examples while reading and I came across something that really stumped me.

So you've got your classic diamond MI example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print "A"

class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print "C"

class D(B, C):
    pass

instance = D()
```

In all MRO resources I've read, this example should have an MRO of DBCA so initialising D should print "C" but instead it prints "A". Weirdly though, when I change the definition of A, B, C or D to be a subclass of something like `int` it gives me the expected behaviour of printing "C"

Why does a class structure's MRO behave differently depending whether a base class is a primitive type? is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

As I was typing this I [read a bit more](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236275) about MRO and discovered that (as far as I know from a cursory understanding) python has old-style (pre 2.2) classes and new-style classes. old-style MRO is left to right depth-first (which would give DBAC) and new-style is an algorithm called C3 which is what I assumed all python 2.7 classes use. Applying the C3 algorithm to a new style class with this inheritance hierarchy gives DBCA. Basically in 2.7, classes that inherit from `Object` are new-style and classes that don't are old-style. I was confusing 2.7 with 3.0 where all classes inherit from `Object` anyway. So if any of the bases of `D` inherited from a new-style class they would give `D` a new-style MRO, otherwise `D` in this example would have an old style MRO.

This is a cool little quirk that I think more people should be aware of. Hope that makes sense.